# I have a multilevel dropdown menu, I want to give some time when we mouseout from the menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

Following is the link http://www.software.slb.com/, i have a multilevel drop down menu, when i move mouseout of the menu the menu should stay for minimum 3 secs, currently its moving away very fast. Any help please.

//This is js code//

```
 $(".flyout-menu").children('.navbar-nav').children('li').find("a").each(function (index, value) {
        $(value).mouseover(function () {
            $(".sub-level1 .list-inline").show();
            var parentID = $(this).text().replace(' ', '_');
            $(".sub-level1").show();
            $(".sub-level1 .list-inline").not("ul#" + parentID + ".list-inline").hide();
        });
    });
    $(".sub-level1").mouseover(function () {
        $(".sub-level1").css({ display: 'block' });
    });

    $(".sub-level1 .level1li").mouseover(function () {
        SetCommonHeight();
    });

    $(".sub-level2").mouseover(function () {
        $(".sub-level2").css({ display: 'block' });
        $(this).css('height', 'auto');
        SetCommonHeight();
    });


        $(".sub-level3").mouseover(function () {
        $(".sub-level2").css('height', 'auto');
        $(this).css('height', 'auto');
        SetCommonHeight();
    });
    $(".section, .main-header").mouseover(function () {
        $(".sub-level1").css({ display: 'none' });
    });
    if ($("ul#Communities li.level1li a").length == 0) {

        $("ul#Communities li.level1li").hide();
    }


    function SetCommonHeight() {
        var max = 1;
        $('div[class^="sub-level"]:visible').each(function () {
            var h = $(this).height();
            max = h > max ? h : max;
        });
        if ($('div[class^="sub-level"]:visible').length < 3) {
            $(".sub-level2:visible").css('height', 'auto');
        }
        else {
            $(".sub-level2:visible").height(max);
        }
        if ($('div[class^="sub-level"]:visible').length < 3) {
            $(".sub-level3:visible").css('height', 'auto');
        }
        else {
            $(".sub-level3:visible").height(max);
        }
        $(".sub-level4:visible").height(max);
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make an onmouseout function for that menu, that do the same thing like onmouseover function does, But for 3 seconds. You can use settimeout function for delay.
In this way, when the mouse is out from the menu, the above function executes. And after 3 seconds it will be disappear like what is happening now on ounmouseover.

Good luck.

Comment: I have written this code for onmouseout but the menu is going away after few seconds,before i mouseout,  $(".sub-level2").mouseout(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert("out");
            $('.sub-level2').css('background-color', '#49616a');
        }, 10000);
    });